# Cannot create AVD in Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am trying to create AVD in AVD manager (Android Studio 3.0.1).
When studio was 1st installed I have selected only 2 system images to download, it were P (Preview) and Oreo, later I have downloaded few more. Now when I am trying to create new AVD and selecting previous versions of Android - button NEXT is inactive. It's getting active only when I am selecting P or Oreo system images.
[image]

I have one AVD with Oreo and it runs great.

What should I do to fix this issue?

[image]
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1dxe.png)

Comment: What do you see on the x86 tab of the System Images page?

Comment: go to x86 images tab and see if you could download any of those?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see the list of images, P and Oreo are active. **Oreo x86-64** is inactive but button **Download** is there. I cannot select and download any other x86 Images

Comment: Issue was fixed by downloading and installing latest Android studio Patch, It was suggested by studio to install it.